# Why is mass times position not used in physics?

Tags: mass, momentum, velocity, definition

The momentum $\vec{p}=m \vec{v}$ plays a very prominent role in physics. 
Why is the same not true for the quantity $\vec{q}=m \vec{r}$?

E.g. one can write angular momentum as $\vec{L} = \vec{r} \times \vec{p}$ but from the rules for the cross product we could equally also write
$$
\vec{L} = \vec{r} \times \vec{p} = \vec{r} \times m\vec{v} = m \vec{r} \times \vec{v} = \vec{q} \times \vec{v}
$$
Similarly in quantum mechanics we have the canonical commutation relation
$$
i\hbar = \left[\hat{r},\hat{p}\right] = \left[\hat{r}, m \hat{v}\right] = \left[m \hat{r}, \hat{v}\right] = \left[\hat{q},\hat{v}\right]
$$
So from these examples one could get the impression that $q$ and $p$ play very symmetric roles in physics. But the quantity $q$ doesn't even have a name, or does it? Why is mass times position not used in physics?

Comment: It does if the body is in a force field.

Comment: Did you look at the definition of center of mass?

Comment: Look at moments of inertia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Calculating_moment_of_inertia_about_an_axis   The useful value $distance^2\times mass$,  where distance is measured from an axis of rotation.

Comment: @CuriousOne : Oh, I completely overlooked the definition of center of mass. But still the quantity $q=m r$ doesn't have a name, although it is used to compute the center of the mass.  Is there also something like a center of mass velocity $V= 1/M \sum_i m_i v_i$?

Comment: I think it is a fair question.

Comment: The question has it the wrong way around: Physics does not proceed by jotting down random quantities and then trying to find some use for them. We use the quantities we use because they have proven useful for describing some aspect of physics. I'm not sure how this question is suppsed to have a identifiable correct answer - if we truly don't use the quantity, then what can an answer say except that we don't use it, and if we *do* use it somewhere, then the premise of the question is just false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call this quantity "first moment of mass" or just "moment of mass". Have a look at [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(physics)) to read about the general concept of moments in physics.

As pointed out in the comments to your question, the first moment of mass is closely related to the center of mass (CoM). For a collection of particles with masses $m_i$ and positions $\vec{r}_i$, the first moment of mass is $\vec{q} = \Sigma m_i \vec{r}_i$ and the position of the CoM is $\vec{r_{com}} = \frac{\Sigma m_i \vec{r}_i}{\Sigma m_i}$. Thus $\vec{r_{com}} = \frac{\vec{q}}{\Sigma m_i}$. This means many statements about $\vec{q}$ can be rephrased in terms of $\vec{r_{com}}$.

The center of mass is a purely geometrical quantity, unlike the moment of mass. It could also be argued that the center of mass is a more intuitive and simple concept. This may explain why the moment of mass is relatively obscure.

One place where I have seen the moment of mass being used and recorded explicitly is in aerospace engineering. I once did a work experience placement with an aircraft manufacturer that kept a database of all components in a particular aircraft. Two of the fields recorded for every component were mass and first moment of mass (relative to some fixed origin, I think it was the nose of the plane). I guess storing information in this way slightly simplified center of mass calculations when components were replaced/removed due to maintenance.